# How can i change the colour of bar chart based on values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having an iplot with certain values filtered  by condition. Need to change colour for specfic sets.

```
Example -
          values 4-6 green
          values >6 red
          Need this in IPLOT
```

Currently the graph has same colour for all values.

Please find the graph here https://plot.ly/~madanraj/30

My code

```
a=df['Woda'].value_counts()
a.iplot(asUrl=True,kind='bar',color=color,title ="KPI Report",filename='Kpi',xTitle='No of Days',yTitle='Number of Incidents')
```

NOTE: df['Woda'] has values from 5-200, nothing much on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with `matplotlib.pyplot` as follows:

```
# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Woda':np.random.randint(5,200,100)})

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

# change bins to range(4,201) if it's the actual data range
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(df.Woda, bins=range(0,200))

plt.xticks(range(0,200,20))

for i in range(4,len(patches)):
    # if you want color by value_counts: 
    # plt.setp(patches[i], 'facecolor','g' if patches[i].get_height()<7 else 'r')
    plt.setp(patches[i], 'facecolor','g' if i<7 else 'r')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Then, if you really need `plotly` figure, use `plotly.tools` to convert it.